# My code doesnt add letters to string in cycle for discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord

```
if(command === "123")
 { 
   var login = "D";
   var password = "D";
   var letters = ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", 
   "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z");
   for(let c = 1; c > 10; c++){
     let randIntP = randomInteger(0,23);
     let randIntL = randomInteger(0,23);
     login += letters[randIntL];
     password += "A";
   }
   password += "123";
   message.channel.send("login - " + login + "\n" + "password - " + password);
 }
```

message that bot sends : "login - D password - D123"

what have i done wrong ?

Comment: `for(let c = 1; c > 10; c++){` will never execute, you maybe meant `c <= 10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`letters` is not an array, in js you declare arrays in `[]`:

```
var letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", 
   "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
```

Your `letters` just contains the letter `"z"`

Also `for (let c = 1; c > 10; c++)` is never `true`.
You want `let c = 1; c < 10; c++`

And at last: 
I guess ou want to replace `password += "A";` with `password += letters[randIntP]`

here's your code:

```js
 
   var login = "D";
   var password = "D";
   var letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", 
   "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
   for(let c = 1; c < 10; c++){
     let randIntP = randomInteger(0,23);
     let randIntL = randomInteger(0,23);
     login += letters[randIntL];
     password += letters[randIntP];
   }
   password += "123";
   console.log("login - " + login + "\n" + "password - " + password);
   
   
   function randomInteger(l, h){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * h ) + l;  
   }
```